# Calculating the child's opacity when the parent has a specific opacity

Tags: css

I have parent element whose opacity is 0.5 . I want child opacity to be 0.3 .

what should be the value for opacity for child element

Comment: @fcalderan Child is more transparent, not less opaque. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to have `0.6` Opacity on something that's already having `0.5` Opacity to have the final opacity to be `0.3`.

Simple math:

```
0.5 × x = 0.3 (this is what we want)
0.5   1
--- = -
0.3   x
0.3 / 0.5 = 0.6 = x
```

```css
.parent, .child {padding: 5px;}
.parent {background: #f00; opacity: 0.5;}
.child {background: #f00; opacity: 0.6;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add two elements, one with an rgba color and the other with the opacity so we can better see the correct result: https://jsfiddle.net/8wa4q6h2/1/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman I would use CSS variables to better control this:

```css
.parent {
  opacity: var(--op, 0.5);
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: calc(var(--oc)/var(--op, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="--oc:0.3">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:50px;background:rgba(0,0,255,0.3)"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="--oc:0.4">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:50px;background:rgba(0,0,255,0.4)"></div>
```

You may notice that you can only have an opacity value between `0` and `op` which is logical since the child cannot be more opaque than it's parent and because the formula won't allow bigger values (you will have an opacity `> 1` which is invalid).